# AdminDirectory.Members.list search by email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Im running a function that receives an email address, then checks if this email is registered in the group, and only if it is not, adds it as a new member

the checking is done by running the following function:

```
  function CheckIfMemberExist(email)
  {
  var MemberExist = false;
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  var groupEmail = 'MyGroupEmail';
  var groupDomainName = 'MyGroupDomain';

  do {
      page = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail,{
      domain: groupDomainName,
      orderBy: 'Email',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
      });
    var members = page.members;
    if (members) 
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
      {
        var memberEmail = members[i].email;
        if(memberEmail.toLowerCase() == email.toLowerCase())
          MemberExist = true;
      }
    } 
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return MemberExist;
}
```

then, only if the function returned **MemberExist = false**, I call:

AdminDirectory.Members.insert(NewMember, groupEmail);

the problem is that sometimes, even though **CheckIfMemberExist** returns false, when I run **AdminDirectory.Members.insert**, I get:
**API call to directory.members.insert failed with error: Member already exist**
and the script breaks.
I somehow suspects that google recognizes a situation where a user has another email associated with the one Im trying to register, but I dont know how to get by this 
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a member to the group using their email it will work. But if you later try to add another member with any alias associated with the first email inserted, it won't work. The same issue applies when you add a member using an alias and afterwards try to add it using the email address.

A solution for your problem would be to use the `Members:list` from the G Suite Admin SDK and then for each member in the list to use the `Users:get`.

The `Users:get` will return a list representing the [`User resource`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) in which you will also find all the emails associated with that user, including the aliases. Afterwards, you can simply check if any of those emails are already in your group. In this way you can avoid the problem that you are currently encountering.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at these links, since they might be of help.

1. [G Suite Admin Help - Problem With Adding a New Member](https://support.google.com/a/forum/AAAA034zvV8_2BlvvbY9Sg/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fapps%2F_2BlvvbY9Sg%3Bcontext-place%3Dtopicsearchin%2FApps%2Fcategory%243Agoogle-groups-for-business%257Csort%3Arelevance%257Cspell%3Afalse);
2. [G Suite Admin SDK - Inserting Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert);
3. [G Suite Admin SDK - Listing Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list);
4. [G Suite Admin SDK - Getting Users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get).